# mat-tab dynamic content with c3js

Tags: angular, angular-material, c3.js

I am trying to get a dynamic tab and in each to have a c3.js chart.

```
            <mat-tab-group dynamicHeight animationDuration="1000ms"
                           disableRipple (selectedTabChange)="Change($event)">

             <mat-tab *ngFor="let workplace of workplaceList;let i = index"
                     label="{{this.workplace}}" input type="text">

              <div id="chart" class="c3"></div>
             </mat-tab>
            </mat-tab-group>
```

First tab is always populated. The others are empty.
When i go back and forward to tab 2, the chart magically apears, but can never get the last or all to load at the sametime.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: how you are calling your chart generate function in ts ?

Comment: `c3.generate({
        data:`

Comment: where you adding reference like #chart   ? in this 3.generate

Comment: you are generating charts all the time  in selectedTabChange events ?

Comment: This is how I am doing it i have method loadAll() which is called once OnInit, then I call it when the tab is changed I tried (selectedTabChange) (selectedIndexChange) nothing really its the same graph, but with diffrent data from the backend (i can see the data is there in the JSON in network tab, but c3 is not redrawn

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `c3.generate` call in the `(selectedTabChange)="Change($event)"` change event method.

As in mat-tab , particular tab html data is loaded in the DOM after you click on that tab.

and as you open tab , call the generate function to plot chart.

**[EDIT]**
checkout this link.
i have used your static data c3 and mat tab code.

https://angular-ivy-cybcss.stackblitz.io/

What i did is have a **unique #id** of chart div for each tab.
then on change event simply generated chart in the respective chart id.

Comment: This is how I am doing it i have method loadAll() which is called once OnInit, then I call it when the tab is changed I tried (selectedTabChange) (selectedIndexChange) nothing really its the same graph, but with diffrent data from the backend (i can see the data is there in the JSON in network tab, but c3 is not redrawn

Comment: can you create a stackblitz demo for same issue ? will check and sort there

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cnttkx I added it , but unfortunalty i cannot add the backend of the project.

Comment: hey i checke d link is not working , , no need to add backend , and this much code, just simply add c3 chart with static data (your response) and mat-tab in stackblitz,   (c3 data and mat-tab only)  then can esaily see issue produced and will debug it.

Comment: i cant really add the back end :/ i can try to replace with a fixed array, but even when i add just a standard c3js on mat-tab example i have the same issue on the following tabs there is no chart :/

Comment: yes ,  just share fixed array c3 and mat tab stackblitz , will look in to working code  issues and then try to sort .. , working issues example all that is needed . , (where one can see issues)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uqds3j i can't get c3 to get installed :/

Comment: @CodeM7 checkout  updated answer , and in stack-blitz , left hand side setting option is here in the menu , try turning off ivy mode , some library still not compatible that's why it seems not to be working

Comment: Still doesn't want to start now the problem is cdk :/